# ASROCK Fatal1ty X370 motherboard: Compatibility SSD

Tags: motherboard, hard-disk, ssd

Currently I am looking to buy SSD, my first one at any rate, and I have seen all kind of SSD (internal, vertical, M.2 to name a few).

I am seriously considering this motherboard (huge upgrade for me going from AM2+ 1075T CPU to an AMD4 cpu) ASROCK Fatal1ty X370 pro gaming.

http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/Fatal1ty%20X370%20Professional%20Gaming/#Specification

I can see it has support for two M.2 sockets (1x M.2_1 and 1x M.2_2).

Question: How do I know what kind of SSD is compatible with this motherboard and what is different between "vertical, internal, and M.2" SSD and will this motherboard support all type?

Comment: This question is too broad to make a specific answer :( However, as a rule of thumb, get a Samsung 960 Evo SSD (M.2 NVMe-based, should work with the board you linked), if you can afford it or a 850 Evo SSD if you can't (SATA3-based, will work most definitely)

Comment: $500 dollar SSD?! Definitely way out of my budget. How is "what is different  between vertical, internal, and M.2" very broad?

Comment: a) There are ~5 different sizes for each of the two SSDs. Prices range from $90 for 120GB / SATA-3 over $150 for the (much faster) 250GB M.2 SSD to $1200 for the 2TB M.2 and $1500 for the 4TB SATA-3 one. b) Your question makes it very hard to _recommend a specific SSD model_ because you neither stated price constraints nor performance or size preferences. c) If you only want an answer as to what the different adjectives mean with regards to SSDs, this _should be_ fine, but I can't help you there precisely ;) d) If you want instructions on how to verify compatibility, this should be doable.

Comment: I don't have a price because I am still getting thing put together. I don't know if I am getting a new case or not for example. Also I updated my question a bit.